# Garbage Collector didn't trigger

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

We have an application which has a JVM heap (Xmx) of about 300 GB . We have Parallel GC for new generation and CMS for old gen.

We have a script which tracks JVM details ( eden , survivor 0 and 1 and old gen space ). It uses `jstat -gc <pid> 5000`. Then we add all the `EU+S0U+S1U+OU` to find the heap space used

We have noticed sometimes that total memory of JVM spikes to around 290 GB (~90% of whole space ) for a span of 1-2 secs and falls back .

But the problem is when we look at GC logs , we can see only parallel GC which ran at that time . No trace of CMS .

If so then how come the old generation got cleaned . Some thing should have cleared the space

Any idea would be of great help.

Thannks

Comment: Please include a relevant snippet of your script to see how are you reading JVM details.

Comment: It's :  jstat -gc <pid> 5000 . Then we add all the EU+S0U+S1U+OU to find the heap space used.

Comment: Can you show how you know the old gen got cleaned and how you know CMS didn't run? Just because usage drops doesn't mean the old gen is being cleaned.